# Is there a way to convert a collection into a model on Laravel 9?

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I do have this method that returns a Collection. Works fine, but I can't use the `update()` method. Let's see some code:

Everything starts at:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        try {
            $validatedData = $request->validate([
                'id_vendor' => 'required',
                'id_type_homologation' => 'required',
                'id_status_invite' => 'required',
            ]);

            $invite = $this->inviteService->updateInvite($id, $validatedData);

            if (! $invite) {
                throw new ModelNotFoundException();
            }

            return $this->sendResponse($invite, 'Convite atualizado com sucesso');
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return $this->sendError('Convite não encontrado', [], 404);
        } catch (ValidationException $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e->errors(), [], 422);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e->getMessage(), [], 500);
        }
    }
```

Here is what `sendResponse()` does:

```
/**
     * success response method.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function sendResponse($result, $message)
    {
        $response = [
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $result,
            'message' => $message,
        ];

        return response()->json($response, 200);
    }
```

then goes to:

```
public function updateInvite(int $id, array $data): \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    {
        return $this->inviteRepository->updateInvite($id, $data);
    }
```

And finally...

```
public function updateInvite(int $id, array $data): \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    {
        try {
            $schema = $this->getAuthenticatedUserSchema();
            $invite = Invite::findBySchemaAndId($schema, $id)->first();

            $data['modified_by'] = auth()->user()->id;
            $invite->update($data);

            return collect([$invite]);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new ModelNotFoundException('Convite não encontrado');
        }
    }
```

That's the error PHP Storm shows:
[image]

The error is:

```
Error
PHP 8.1.21
9.52.10
Call to undefined method stdClass::update()
```

There is a way to convert this collection into a model or something that makes a way to use the `update()` method?

Comment: How are you calling `updateInvite` and how are you using the result?

Comment: Added some more code, hope can help!

Comment: What does `sendResponse` do? If I were to guess  I would guess that you are serialising and sending the data somewhere and then reconstructing it somewhere else at which point it's no longer a model instance. It's not clear whether or not this is the case though.

Comment: It seem that this project is adopting the Repository/Service pattern to access to data.
I think that with Eloquent at hand, the Repository pattern creates unnecessary overhead.
And if you're now using Eloquent bypassing the Repository, it's just confusing.
Anyway, you can try to create a Model from scratch and copy the collection attributes, like this: 
`$inviteModel = new Invite; $inviteModel->fill($invite->all());`

Comment: `Illuminate\Support\Collection` itself already has such functionality that can convert given collection into class - [mapInto](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-mapinto). For simple tables that do not have relations it probably would be ok. It would be also great if you would share more context of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This error is nothing to do with collections. You try to call `update()` method on a generic object. You've elected not to share any of the error details, but presumably this is triggered when you call `$invite->update($data)`. So look at what `$invite` is. Figure out why it isn't what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to make it work!

```
public function updateInvite(int $id, array $data): \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    {
        try {
            $schema = $this->getAuthenticatedUserSchema();
            $invite = Invite::findBySchemaAndId($schema, $id)->first();

            $invite = new Invite();
            $invite->id_vendor = $data['id_vendor'];
            $invite->id_type_homologation = $data['id_type_homologation'];
            $sendDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['send_date']));
            $invite->send_date = $sendDate;
            $invite->id_status_invite = $data['id_status_invite'];
            $invite->modified_by = auth()->user()->id;
            $acceptanceDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['acceptance_date']));
            $invite->acceptance_date = $acceptanceDate;
            $expirationDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($data['expiration_date']));
            $invite->expiration_date = $expirationDate;

            DB::statement("
            UPDATE $schema.invites
            SET id_vendor = {$invite->id_vendor},
                id_type_homologation = {$invite->id_type_homologation},
                send_date = '{$invite->send_date}',
                id_status_invite = {$invite->id_status_invite},
                modified_by = {$invite->modified_by},
                acceptance_date = '{$invite->acceptance_date}',
                expiration_date = '{$invite->expiration_date}'
            WHERE id = $id
        ");

            return collect([$invite]);
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            throw new ModelNotFoundException('Convite não encontrado');
        }
    }
```

Comment: This just screams you're doing something extremely wrong at some point in your code. I assumed `findBySchemaAndId` returns an instance of `Invite` and `Invite` extends `Model` (the base eloquent model) but it seems that is incorrect.

Comment: Well, it worked just fine, but we have changed the concept and this method is not necessary anymore. Go figure!